# Disable Suggestions For NumberDecimal Keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, keyboard

I have a custom edittext and i need exactly the keyboard that `andorid:inputType="numberDecimal"` shows, (numeric keyboard with decimal dot only), and i have code in the textwatcher to format the number with dots an decimal comma, accord to my country.
The problem, is in new Android API´S, when suggestions are enabled, it changes the way of the textwatcher works.
I didn´t found how to turn off the suggestions for the numberDecimal Keyboard.
I´ve tried all the combinations, like:

`numberDecimal|textNoSuggestions` (it shows alphanumeric keyboard)

Thanks!